# Soundtrack of Naruto and Naruto Shippuden

Tags: naruto, music

Where I can find all the soundtracks which are used in Naruto and Naruto Shippuden episodes?

Answer (score 2):

An *extensive* list of the music used throughout the entire Naruto franchise is available [on the Naruto Wiki](http://naruto.wikia.com/wiki/Music).  This includes a full list of:

- Openings
- Endings
- Various soundtracks at different points in the series
- Movie soundtracks

As a fan of the show, I would strongly encourage you to purchase the media from legal and reputable channels when possible.  As an example, [here is an Amazon link](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B00008DZ3H) which points you at the first soundtrack; from there, you should be able to track down the others.